# Service isn't implementing interface member noobie

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, architecture, interface, repository

I am re engineering an MVC3 app to take all linq out of controllers and in to proper layers.

I have got this as my structure SQL --> EF --> Repository --> Service --> Controller. I am using interfaces.

When compiling I am getting this error:

gpc.data.service.roleService does not implement interface member gpc.data.interfaces.iroleservice.HolderNamesbyRoleID(int).

I am totally new to proper architecture so apologies if this is blindingly obvious lol. Here is some code:

Repository:

```
namespace gpc.Data.Repositories
{
public class roleRepository :gpc.Data.Interfaces.IRoleRepository
{
private gpc.Models.gpcEntities _entities = new Models.gpcEntities();


public HolderNames HolderNamesbyRoleID(int roleid)
{
return (from i in _entities.HolderNames
where i.roleid == roleid select i).FirstOrDefault();              
}
}
}
```

I then have an interface:

```
namespace gpc.Data.Interfaces
{
public interface IRoleRepository
{
HolderNames HolderNamesbyRoleID(int roleid);
}
}
```

Then I have the service:

```
namespace gpc.Data.Service
{
public class roleService : gpc.Data.Interfaces.IRoleService
{
    private ModelStateDictionary _modelState;
    private gpc.Data.Interfaces.IRoleRepository _repository;

    public roleService(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        _modelState = modelState;
        _repository = new gpc.Data.Repositories.roleRepository();
    }
    public roleService(ModelStateDictionary modelState,                                    
    gpc.Data.Repositories.roleRepository repository)
    {
        _modelState = modelState;
        _repository = repository;
    }


    public HolderNames HolderNames(int roleid)
    {
        return _repository.HolderNamesbyRoleID(roleid);
    }
}
}
```

I then have another interface:

```
namespace gpc.Data.Interfaces
{
public interface IRoleService
{
    HolderNames HolderNamesbyRoleID(int roleid);
}
}
```

I created a very simple ienumerable in this structure and I was able to get data on to the view through the controller as i would expect. I guess that as this one is a bit more complicated that a select everything and throw it at a view I must have missed something. I don't know if it makes a difference, but "holdernames" is a SQL view as opposed to a table.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically just what your compiler error shows. Your `IRoleService` interface defines a method named `HolderNamesbyRoleID`, but in your implementation you only have a method named `HolderNames`.

I assume this is just a mistype on your part.

Answer (score 0):

Interface only contains the signature. You have to write actual implementation in class where you have implemented your interface. In your case you have define method **HolderNamesbyRoleID** in  **IRoleRepository** but you have not implemented this method in **roleService** class. You must have to implement **HolderNamesbyRoleID** in **roleService** class.

Your **roleService** class code becomes like below.

```
namespace gpc.Data.Service
{
public class roleService : gpc.Data.Interfaces.IRoleService
{
    private ModelStateDictionary _modelState;
    private gpc.Data.Interfaces.IRoleRepository _repository;

    public roleService(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        _modelState = modelState;
        _repository = new gpc.Data.Repositories.roleRepository();
    }
    public roleService(ModelStateDictionary modelState,                                    
    gpc.Data.Repositories.roleRepository repository)
    {
        _modelState = modelState;
        _repository = repository;
    }


    public HolderNames HolderNamesbyRoleID(int roleid)
    {
        return _repository.HolderNamesbyRoleID(roleid);
    }
}
}
```

Refer [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more info.